# Windows Service and TThread

Tags: delphi

I'm new to Windows Service, and I need to do this work...
I got my code from [here](http://www.cromis.net/blog/2011/04/how-to-make-a-very-small-windows-service-executable/), and this is just a copy from this code. But I'm trying to do some HTTP request from the service. For this job, I choose to create a new thread, and do the request inside the thread... This part of the code is (it's the only thing I added from the original code on the link above):

```
type
  MyThread = class(TThread)
  strict private

  protected
    constructor Create;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor MyThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FreeOnTerminate:= true;
  Priority:= tpNormal;
end;

procedure MyThread.Execute;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  while not(Terminated) do
  begin
    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    IdHTTP.Get('http://google.com');
    IdHTTP.Free;
    Sleep(5000);
  end;
end;
```

I call the MyThread.Create procedure, inside the *OnServiceCreate*, but it makes only one request. It shouldn't do one request each 5 seconds, while the Thread is alive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I call the MyThread.Create procedure, inside the OnServiceCreate

The `TService.OnCreate` event is the wrong place to create your thread.  That event is triggered not only when the service is started, but also when the service is (un)installed.  Create the thread in the `OnStart` event instead, which is triggered only when the service is started.

> it makes only one request. It shouldn't do one request each 5 seconds, while the Thread is alive?

Your thread is not doing any error handling.  If `TIdHTTP.Get()` fails for any reason, it raises an exception that you are not catching, and so your thread will terminate itself.

There is also no reason to re-create the `TIdHTTP` object on every loop iteration.

And I strongly suggest you NOT use `FreeOnTerminate=true` at all.  Leave it false, and then terminate and free the thread in the `OnStop`/OnShutdown` events instead.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  MyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor MyThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure MyThread.Execute;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      try
        IdHTTP.Get('http://google.com');
        // success, do something
      except
        // failed, do something else
      end;
      Sleep(5000);
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
type
  TService1 = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
  private
    Thread: MyThread;
  end;

procedure TService1.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  Thread := MyThread.Create;
  Started := True;
end;

procedure TService1.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  if Thread <> nil then
  begin
    Thread.Terminate;
    while WaitForSingleObject(Thread.Handle, WaitHint-100) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
      ReportStatus;
    FreeAndNil(Thread);
  end;
  Stopped := True;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for the explanation about the ServiceStart/Stop... The original code, hadn't this implementation. I'll try to bring it to my code, anyway the request was solved with the try/except so it's all good. Thank you!